# Is there a Get/Put S3 private object via CloudFront by using S3 pre signed url?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, pre-signed-url

I do lots of research and seems not meet my needs. I want to get my private object in S3 via Cloudfront. In my current implementation, I am using S3 pre-signed url to do Get and Put Object in my private bucket. Now, I would like to combine CloudFront in my App. Is there a way still using S3 presigned url and via Cloudfront to access my object? Do I need a OAI/OAC
I only find the res in this [website](https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-use-s3-signed-urls-with-cloudfront/). However, it is not so clear to me.

Any comments will be appreciated!!

Note:

1. I do not want to use "CloudFront signed url". That is the most resource that I found in the internet.
2. I do not want to use "s3 transfer acceleration"